# why doesn't has_many :through work here...is there a hidden limitation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This question is for Rails 3.0.0.

I have 5 tables (contrived but reasonable example, only 4 matter):

```
capabilities
    id
    name

capability_roles
    role_id
    capability_id

user_roles
    user_id
    role_id

users
    id
    name

roles
    id
    name
```

Basically capabilities connects to roles_capabilities connects to user_roles
connects to users.

The *_roles tables are simply maps. They have no primary key. The roles
table itself is almost incidental to this question.

This allows the capabilities of each role be edited independently of the
roles users are allowed to assume.

It would be nice to *simply* figure out which capabilities a user has.

Now set up associations:

```
users
    has_many :user_roles  # .joins( :user_roles ).to_sql # works

user_roles
    belongs_to :user # .joins( :user ).to_sql # works

    # .joins( :capability_roles ).to_sql # works (no corresponding belongs_to!)
    has_many :capability_roles, :primary_key => role_id, :foreign_key => :role_id

    # .joins( :capabilities ).to_sql # fails
    has_many :capabilities, :through => :capability_roles

capability_roles
    belongs_to :capabilities # .joins( :capabilities ).to_sql # works

    # .joins( :user_roles ).to_sql # works (no corresponding belongs_to!)
    has_many :user_roles, :primary_key => role_id, :foreign_key => :role_id

    # .joins( :users ).to_sql # fails
    has_many :users, :through => :user_roles 

capabilities
    has_many :capability_roles  # .joins( :capability_roles ).to_sql # works
```

My question is:

Why doesn't has_many :through work here?

It seems like what has_many :through was designed for. I'm not sure if
the missing/irrelevant belongs_to()'s are an issue.

The failure I see is:
     NoMethodError: undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Are you specifying the names of your linking tables anywhere? I'm pretty sure Rails doesn't infer the name unless it's plural_plural

Comment: Can you post the code in your controller that you are attempting to run? That way we can determine the disconnect between what you want to do, and how your models are set up.

Comment: this comment deleted. It landed in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 2):

The join tables you are using are designed for `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships, not `has_many`, and are not expected to have associated classes. I'd go with something like this:

```
Role
  has_and_belongs_to_many :capabilities
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  has_many :capabilities # use SQL with sub-select through roles to get the capabilities

Capability
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  has_many :users # use SQL with sub-select through roles to get the users
```

Comment: Your answer causes confusion, because there's a whole bunch of quotes like (from the book The Rails 3 Way by Obie Fernandez, et al)

Comment: Your answer causes confusion, because there's a whole bunch of quotes around like (from the book The Rails 3 Way by Obie Fernandez, et al)

"Josh Susser is considered the expert on Active Record associations... The has_many :through association allows you to specify a one-to-many relationship indirectly via the same table, which effectively makes it a replacement for has_and_belongs_to many. The biggest advantage is that the join table contains full-fledged objects .... No more push_with_attributes; join models just work the same way all your other Active Record models do.

Comment: As the text you quoted states, the reason to use `has_many :through` is when the join table contains more attributes than simply the joining IDs - this makes it useful as its own model. In your case, you are only showing the join IDs in your join table, so it does not make sense as a separate model. Based on your example, habtm is the best association choice.